# Clone repository computer A to remote B doesnt work

Tags: git

I've recently use Git on my windows work pc, I cloned my code to a pendrive in order to have a copy using git clone and everything was ok. I bought a NAS (linux based) and I want to do the same. The connection with ssh works fine.

I have installed git for windows but I didn't installed nothing in the other machine (NAS Linux based).

I try do this:

```
git clone user@IP:/directory/where/i/want/clone
```

It doesn't work because I obtain this after I write the password:

```
sh: git-upload-pack: command not found
```

I found here a possible solution: I need add -u /path/to/git-upload-pack. So I write:

```
git clone -u /c/Git/mingw64/bin/git-upload-pack user@IP:/directory/where/i/want/clone
```

After I write the password and I obtain:

```
sh: C:/Git/mingw64/bin/git-upload-pack: No such file or directory.
```

But it exists! (in my local windows work pc)

I'm a newbie with Git and Unix system. What can I do ?
I just want first clone to remote computer and then use something like "git pull/push"
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. 
I **need install git in my NAS** server, then with ssh I created a bare repository. Now I can do :

```
git clone user@ip:/directory/of/repository/bare/created.
```

Then you can do changes and create files, commit the changes and finally do:

```
git push
```

Thanks you,
Regards,
Roberto